# Unable to find action on Lightning Component

Tags: controller, page-layout, action, component, lightining

This is my code but I have the Error
[image]
// DynamicRelatedContactListController.apxc

```
public with sharing class DynamicRelatedContactListController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getRelatedContacts(Id accountId) {
        List<Contact> relatedContacts = [
            SELECT Id, Name, Email
            FROM Contact
            WHERE Id IN (
                SELECT ContactId 
                FROM AccountContactRelation 
                WHERE AccountId = :accountId AND IsActive = true
            )
        ];

        return relatedContacts;
    }
}
```

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
        <p>Name: {!contact.Name}</p>
        <p>Email: {!contact.Email}</p>
        <hr/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

// DynamicRelatedContactListController.js

```
({
    doInit: function(component) {
        var accountId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var action = component.get("c.getRelatedContacts");

        action.setParams({
            "accountId": accountId
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.contacts", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Controller not added on Component. Apex Controller(Server-side controller need to be added on  `aura:component` tag using `controller` attribute.

```
<aura:component controller="DynamicRelatedContactListController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" >
```

**Ref :** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm